# Is 256MB Ram cloud server enough to run a simple web application in PHP?

Tags: php, web-hosting, virtualhost

I have written a simple web application mostly full of static web pages with several you-tube embeddings. Few forms and so on. All this is developed using CodeIgniter.

The site is very similar to Academic Earth. With videos served from Youtube. It has got 400 users only 30-40 are active.

I am not interested in shared hosting and want a machine with root access. My budget allows me to hire RackSpace cloud server with 256MB Ram.

Is it sufficient to run my application?

Or should this question go on ServerFault.

Comment: You might also look into a VPS service such as Linode or Vps.net. These give you root access and you can look at their different packages. I never used RackSpace Cloud server, so I am unsure how it relates to the VPS's.  And I would put it to ServerFault.

Comment: Rackspace Cloud is a VPS hosting service. I've got 3 "machines" running on there quite nicely with Fedora 10. They've got 512meg each, but Linux is quite happy with 256 for basic serving.

Comment: @Marc 
Is it possible to map them with public DNS and use as web servers along with mailing functionality isn't it ?

Comment: Yep. Rackspace gives you real IPs, and control over the reverse mappings as well. Other than the fact that you're running a virtual box inside a Xen hypervisor, there's no practical difference between a cloud "box" and a real physical one.

Comment: Yes, they're practically indistinguishable from real servers, though since they're automatically provisioned, a lot of the IPs are on the SpamHaus Policy Block List (PBL).  You can automatically de-list your IP via SpamHaus to get rid of that email delivery hurdle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great success running apps on tiny VPS hosts like Slicehost and Linode.

You'll probably be fine with the apache/php/mysql from your distribution's package manager.  I've had good results compiling my own AMP stack from source and tweaking things.  With PHP 5.3.3, PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager) is built in, and provides much better FastCGI support.

Running PHP under FastCGI can be adventageous in low-memory situations, since you can then run apache with the worker MPM, which is much more efficient, memory-wise than running prefork-apache/mod_php

Note that currently, Linode will give you a 512MB server for $20/month.  However, my experience has been that Linode has semi-frequent network issues (see http://status.linode.com), but otherwise they've been great.

If all you can afford is $20/month, you probably can't do much better.  The other nice thing about these VPS hosts is that if you need to grow later, all it takes is a couple of clicks in a control panel and you can upsize your server.

Comment: Yes there is a potential that my app might grow greatly in future and at that time money will not be a constraint. Thats why i am looking at clouds.

Comment: Then yes, I'd highly recommend you start with a 512MB instance at linode.  You'll want to document exactly what you do to set up your VPS, so if you ever want to move to another vendor, you'll be in good shape.  I'd suggest writing a shell script that sets up a newly-reimaged server just the way you want it.

Comment: I don't think you answered his question... he didn't ask for an ad... the fact is, per month, he can get 256MB for only $11 on cloud with rackspace, which is cheaper than your proposed $20.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can run a simple server on 256MB RAM. You would want to look at things like http://www.lighttpd.net/ instead of Apache and do some tweaking to settings (I read that Debian is better at using less RAM out-of-the-box though not sure how true that is.)

Read this:
http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/yes-you-can-run-18-static-sites-on-a-64mb-link-1-vps/